# Java binding to ::0 on IPv4-only machine?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, ipv6

I have a Java program that listens for incoming connections on a port. I've been using `0.0.0.0` as the IP address so that it accepts connections on any IP on a multihomed system. Well, any IPv4 address, that is, and so I'd like to switch to the IPv6 equivalent, `::0`, so it will accept incoming IPv6 connections as well... but if this code is then run on an IPv4-only system, will it still work?

**UPDATE**: The binding, in this case, is expressed in the form of a URL - it's to configure an ActiveMQ broker - so I can't provide `null`.

Comment: I remember this being a very well-documented issue. Any chance you're using FreeBSD?

Comment: No - Windows or Red Hat... though I'm really hoping it doesn't depend on the OS!

Comment: So is this a Java issue or an ActiveMQ issue?

Comment: Well, I know that using `0.0.0.0` works for IPv4 and `::0` works for both IPv4 and IPv6, and that it is not specific to ActiveMQ. I don't see it as an ActiveMQ issue except for having to specify *something* rather than `null`. I'm just concerned that if I use the IPv6 form in an IPv4-only environment, something may break... or Java may be smart enough to handle it. I don't know which.

Comment: Please clarify. Who uses this URL in this way? I'm not aware of anywhere in Java where a listen-address is specified via a URL.

Comment: It's part of how ActiveMQ (a JMS implementation) is configured. You can see examples [here](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html) and [here](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-uri.html) and [here](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html). I've established that I can use, e.g., `tcp://[::0]:616161/brokerName` to configure a broker and that on an IPv6 enabled machine, this will also listen on the IPv4 addresses. I need to know whether this will continue to work on an IPv4-only machine.

Comment: Your first and third examples are client configurations, nothing to do with binding at all. I suggest you ask this question on the relevant mailing list.

Comment: Just FWIW, "transport configurations" (the first and third) apply to both client and broker configurations. As for the original question, it's a fairly generic Java question and not actually specific to ActiveMQ (except insofar as `null` won't work): In Java, binding to INADDR_ANY (`0.0.0.0`) gets you all IPv4 addresses; binding to IN6ADDR_ANY (`::0`) gets you you all IPv4 *and* all IPv6 addresses. Will binding to `::0` work if the underlying system doesn't actually support IPv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no; it throws a `SocketException`. I implemented the `[::0]` implementation as specified above, and on one of our machines the following exception was thrown:

```
2014-06-02 11:51:14,050 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR Could not initialize broker Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://[::0]:61616/broker due to: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://[::0]:61616/broker due to: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:133)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.doBind(TcpTransportFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactorySupport.bind(TransportFactorySupport.java:40)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:2294)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.addConnector(BrokerService.java:289)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.addConnector(BrokerService.java:279)
    [...]
```

Ah well, it was worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a listen-address at all. Pass null. Then you will listen on all NICs in whichever of IPv6 and IPv4 are present on your host,